# React Native - Realm - iOS - Build input file cannot be found: .../node_modules/realm/tests/ios/RJSModuleLoader.m'

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

I am trying to install Realm on an existing React Native project. I ran npm install --save realm, and then react-native link realm. In the simulator I get an error for a missing realm constructor. I then followed the recommended steps on https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#missing-realm-constructor by deleting the build and running react-native run-ios. The build fails and I receive 2 errors:

- error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/seantansey/Sites/IntelligentOfficeMobile/node_modules/realm/tests/ios/RJSModuleLoader.m'
- error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/seantansey/Sites/IntelligentOfficeMobile/node_modules/realm/tests/ios/RealmJSCoreTests.m'

I am using:
- React-native v0.60.5
- Realm v3.2.0

Comment: which version of realm you are trying to use?

Comment: i was also facing this issue, although it's not required to link anymore still i did and it's working with warnings when i run react-native run-android

Comment: i am using realm v3.2.0 and trying to run on ios

Comment: in the end, I had to use "realm": "^3.0.0", mine is working fine on iOS as well

Comment: just tried 3.0.0 and got the same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by downgrading to Realm v2.28.0